# Como parar o while quando a condição for verdadeira em Python?

Tags: python, algoritmo

Meu código está assim:

```
x = 0
c = 0
c0, c1, c2, c3, c00 = 100, 101, 102, 103, 0

while x <= 3:
    login = str(input("Digite o login: "))
    senha = int(input("Digite a senha: "))
    x += 1

    if login == 'ifpe' and senha == 12345:
        print("  Código  | Produto          | Preço (R$)")
        print("   100    | Cachorro-quente  |   1,70")
        print("   101    | Bauru simples    |   2,30")
        print("   102    | Bauru com ovo    |   2,60")
        print("   103    | Hambúrguer       |   2,40")
        print("    0     |   Sair")
        print()
        p = input("Digite o código do produto: ")
        q = int(input("Digite a quantidade: "))
        c +=1 
        if p == 100:
            print("Valor: ", 2.30 + c)
    else:
        print("Login e/ou senha inválidos.")
        break
```

Eu quero que pare de pedir o *login* e senha quando ele for digitado corretamente. Como faço pra isso acontecer?

Answer (score 1):

O laço foi criado para controlar justamente se a autenticação foi validada, então é só isso que deve ter dentro do laço, mais nada.

Não vou resolver todos problemas de legibilidade e robustez do código, mas melhorei mais algumas coisas. Também não entrei no mérito da senha ser numérica, ou essas variáveis `c` alguma coisa que provavelmente não deveria ser assim, mas como não usou só retirei.

É possível que queira outro laço para controlar os vários pedidos, mas esse é outro problema que inclusive precisaria de melhor definição. Tem outros pontos esquisitos.

```
x = 0
c = 0
while x < 4:
    login = input("Digite o login: ")
    senha = int(input("Digite a senha: "))
    x += 1
    if login == 'ifpe' and senha == 12345:
        break
    print("Login e/ou senha inválidos.")

print("  Código  | Produto          | Preço (R$)")
print("   100    | Cachorro-quente  |   1,70")
print("   101    | Bauru simples    |   2,30")
print("   102    | Bauru com ovo    |   2,60")
print("   103    | Hambúrguer       |   2,40")
print("    0     |   Sair")
print()
p = input("Digite o código do produto: ")
q = int(input("Digite a quantidade: "))
c += 1 
if p == 100:
    print("Valor: ", 2.30 + c)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/bhIQ24). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/sxppiqhhvb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/Repeat.py).

Comment: e qual seria a forma correta para o while ser interrompido e continuar o resto do algoritmo quando a condição do if for verdadeira e não ficar repetindo os inputs dentro do while até que seja igual a 3 ?

Comment: A forma seria essa que eu coloquei na resposta acima.